# Отсортировать список стран двухпутевым слиянием python

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка-слиянием

Для примера взял поменьше стран. Нужно отсортировать их по заданному континенту и по численности населения. По численности я реализовал, а как сделать, чтобы и по континенту? Например только Азия и по численности населения.

```
class Country:
def __init__(self, make, continent, population):
    self.make = make
    self.continent = continent
    self.population = population

def __str__(self):
    return str.format("Country: {}, continent: {}, population: {}", self.make, self.continent, 
self.population)

def merge(array, left_index, right_index, middle, comparison_function):
left_copy = array[left_index:middle + 1]
right_copy = array[middle+1:right_index+1]

left_copy_index = 0
right_copy_index = 0
sorted_index = left_index

while left_copy_index < len(left_copy) and right_copy_index < len(right_copy):

    # We use the comparison_function instead of a simple comparison operator
    if comparison_function(left_copy[left_copy_index], right_copy[right_copy_index]):
        array[sorted_index] = left_copy[left_copy_index]
        left_copy_index = left_copy_index + 1
    else:
        array[sorted_index] = right_copy[right_copy_index]
        right_copy_index = right_copy_index + 1

    sorted_index = sorted_index + 1

while left_copy_index < len(left_copy):
    array[sorted_index] = left_copy[left_copy_index]
    left_copy_index = left_copy_index + 1
    sorted_index = sorted_index + 1

while right_copy_index < len(right_copy):
    array[sorted_index] = right_copy[right_copy_index]
    right_copy_index = right_copy_index + 1
    sorted_index = sorted_index + 1


def merge_sort(array, left_index, right_index, comparison_function):
if left_index >= right_index:
    return

middle = (left_index + right_index)//2
merge_sort(array, left_index, middle, comparison_function)
merge_sort(array, middle + 1, right_index, comparison_function)
merge(array, left_index, right_index, middle, comparison_function)

Country1 = Country("China", "Asia", 1273111)
Country2 = Country("India", "Asia", 1029991)
Country3 = Country("Japan", "Asia", 126771)
Country4 = Country("Russia", "Europe", 145567)

array = [Country1, Country2, Country3, Country4]

merge_sort(array, 0, len(array) -1, lambda CountryA, CountryB: CountryA.population < 
CountryB.population)
print("Country sorted by population:")
for Country in array:
print(Country)
```

Comment: Из любви к искусству и желания поизвращаться - конечно можно и классы городить, со своими структурами и методами. А можно вспомнить, что в Python специально для таких задач есть чудесненький пакет Pandas, где задачи такого типа решаются в две строчки кода.  Может не стоит велосипед изобретать?

Comment: Мне велосипед нужен

Comment: начнем с того, что приведенный вами код содержит ошибки. Синтаксические.  Как минимум, для начала наведите порядок с отступами.